# warning: Kotlin runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version

Tags: kotlin

I get the following warning, but I'm not sure where v1.0.6 resides.

Is it possible this error comes from a Kotlin library somehow including an old Kotlin version?

Any ideas how to fix it or at least how can I follow the suggestion to make kotlin-reflect explicit (1.1) ?

[image]

Comment: FOR ANDROID DEVELOPERS WITH ERROR OCCURING AT XML UNRECOGNIZED FILE

It if it in Android and thew error appears by not recognizing a xml file, you could search for some error in the xml folder files(in my case, one of the files had tag duplicated)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

It seems that your project is configured in such a way that you depend on `kotlin-stdlib` 1.1 and `kotlin-reflect` 1.0. The most likely case is that you already have an explicit dependency on `kotlin-stdlib` 1.1 but have no dependency on `kotlin-reflect`, and some other library (which you depend on) depends on `kotlin-reflect` 1.0.

If that indeed is the case, the solution is to provide an explicit dependency on `kotlin-reflect` 1.1.

In Maven, add this to `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

In Gradle, add this to `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.0"
}
```

See some info about this and related warnings [in the official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compatibility.html#binary-compatibility-warnings).

Comment: What happens when I upgrade to 1.1.1? Will I get warnings again because of this 1.1.0 new dependency?

Comment: No, the warning is there only when major/minor versions don't match. We're keeping patch version updates fully compatible between one another

Comment: Where is supposed to be located the `pom.xml` file?

Answer (score 57):

firstly, figure out the reason by the gradle script below

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

(change `app` to your gradle module name)

```
+--- project :common
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.61
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.61
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.3.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.61
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:0.12.0 -> 0.14.0
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.60 -> 1.3.61
```

Then, the dependency tree will be shown.
check which dependency use the issue dependency.

If you found the dependency, decide how to solve it.

1. upgrade the dependency's version(the dependency's latest version may refer to latest issue dependency's version)
2. or exclude the issue dependency from the dependency
3. or follow other answers.

I'm not sure what is the best way. kindly just refer to it.

Comment: This is the best way to troubleshoot hidden dependencies.

Answer (score 34):

I fixed warning by overwriting kotlin version used in my app

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'org.jetbrains.kotlin' && requested.name == 'kotlin-reflect') {
            details.useVersion kotlin_version
        }
    }
}
```

e.g. `kotlin_version = 1.3.0`

Comment: I added that but still gets the same error. It is driving me nut man...

Comment: @GithithuWambura put it directly in app build.gradle without bracing in `android {}` e.g.

Comment: /*Alternatively*/
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency {
            if ((requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") && (!requested.name.startsWith("kotlin-gradle"))) {
                useVersion(kotlin_version)
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: For the Gradle Kotlin DSL variant of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73257394/430128

Answer (score 12):

it happens when you are using the dagger in a kotlin project(android) and you have the kotlin version to be 1.7 i.e

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

all you have to do is add the dependency below to your app build gradle level

```
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.50"
```

Comment: I have tryed this but only changes the error message. No luck. Trying to recompile an old project turns into a nightmare!

Answer (score 7):

**Make sure you use the same version of `stdlib-jdk7` & `kotlin-gradle-plugin` dependencies to avoid warnings.**
You can refere below example where `stdlib-jdk7` & `kotlin-gradle-plugin` both have the same version

> app-level build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.0"
    ...
}
```

> project-level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.0" 
         ...
    }
```

}

Answer (score 7):

replace this

```
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.30'
```

with

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.30'
```

the version of library should be same as plugin in project level

```
 classpath org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30
```

Answer (score 3):

For flutter initialized project, I commented this line to refer the already available lib

```
dependencies {
    // implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

and this was gone:

```
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath

w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
```

Answer (score 3):

For me in our react-native project, I just needed to add `kotlinVersion = "1.6.10"` to `buildscript.ext` in `android/build.gradle` file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.10"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what worked for me. At first i was resistant to update kotlin version, and after wasting an hour or so I decided to do so after reading this comment.

Answer (score 2):

The Kotlin version in build.gradle and the one bundled with your IDE are of different versions. Check the kotlin version in build.gradle (app) and in Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates.

Comment: Yup they are different, how to force my project to use a specific version?

Answer (score 1):

When this happens for the Lint task, one can list the dependencies with:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration lintClassPath
```

Which shows that eg. `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32` is being used:

```
 +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.32 (*)
 \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32 (*)
```

---

I've wrote a Gradle script, which equalizes all the Kotlin library versions:

```
// Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version.
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'org.jetbrains.kotlin') {
            List<String> list = ['kotlin-stdlib', 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk7', 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8', 'kotlin-stdlib-common']
            if (list.contains(requested.name)) { details.useVersion kotlinVersion }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no other way, because some older versions are being pulled in by build tools.
One likely could also add `kotlin-reflect` into the `List<String> list` (not tested).

Answer (score 1):

To use the `resolutionStrategy` approach (see @vlad's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081554/430128) with Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```
// this one defines it via rootProject e.g. `gradle.properties`
// change as needed
val kotlinVersion: String by rootProject

configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force(
      "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlinVersion}",
      "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:${kotlinVersion}",
      "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}",
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Photo Point's comment from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081554/2210080) is what worked for me

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency {
            if ((requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") && (!requested.name.startsWith("kotlin-gradle"))) { useVersion(kotlin_version) }
        }
    }
}
```

And added app-level `build.gradle` file:

```
"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Hope this helps as this drove me nuts for some time!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your own version of Kotlin in your project does the work according to the version of your dependencies used.

Worked me by upgrading kotlin from 1.5.21 to 1.6.0 after upgrading Room from 2.3.0 to 2.4.x

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code below into build.gradle inside of android{ //paste code here}
worked;

```
lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I upgraded to gradle Latest Version . that's when i faced this error**

So you only have to delete the old gradle folder and this will fix the issue
/android/.gradle