# Android Studio shows Kotlin Dependency Warning after Second Build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I've just enabled Kotlin in my Android project and I stumbled upon a warning. After the second build (Build -> Rebuild Project) this warning is shown under Messages:

```
Warning:Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.2.10/85fe1811f3e586d0cc53aba1394d8089f1862215/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.10.jar (version 1.2)
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.10/19bc012f8c4cd6b705bd6512263777cc19bcf259/kotlin-reflect-1.2.10.jar (version 1.2)
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.51/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.51.jar (version 1.1)
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.10/cfe8b616b3bf0811ef70863c86b745a2e767a66e/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.10.jar (version 1.2)
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.10/b9bf650516989595a5390e5a54181e16347208ac/kotlin-stdlib-1.2.10.jar (version 1.2)
```

It seems like the second build includes the outdated `kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.51.jar` from cache. After a clean build (Build -> Clean Project) the warning is gone, and the next Rebuild Project brings it up again.

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and I explicitly include the Kotlin dependencies with version:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        // shared build properties
        kotlin_version      = '1.2.10'
        buildToolsVersion   = '27.0.2'
        minSdkVersion       = 15
        targetSdkVersion    = 27
        compileSdkVersion   = 27
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlin_version}"
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlin_version}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlin_version}"
    [...]
}
```

Also on our [travis builds](https://travis-ci.org/openHPI/xikolo-android/jobs/316915080#L2542) the warning is shown. Thus, it is not only a problem with my local setup. Even if it is only a warning, I don't feel comfortable by releasing an apk that includes conflicting versions.

Comment: You can also check this for correct integrations 
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Summary

1. You already fixed it updating your dependencies but I'll answer here to link a related question.
2. You configured correctly your project dependencies and updated the Kotlin plugin to 1.2.
3. This is normally enough like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42569445/1009132) but stdlib-jre dependencies were changed to jdk in Kotlin 1.2.
4. But your project was depending on Realm version 4.3.1, and they fixed this in version 4.3.2.
5. You can find the dependency causing the issue via commands or the new build tab in AS 3.1.

---

### 1. Add explicit dependencies and update dependencies

Extended versions of the Kotlin standard library are explained in [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies) and [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170785/unable-to-resolve-dependencies-for-assembleandroidtest-task-with-android-gradle/48184303#48184303)

> If you're **targeting JDK 7 or JDK 8**, you can use extended versions of
>   the Kotlin standard library which contain additional extension
>   functions for APIs added in new JDK versions.
>
> Instead of `kotlin-stdlib`, use one of the following dependencies:
>
> ```
> compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
> compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
> ```
>
> **In Kotlin 1.1.x**, use `kotlin-stdlib-jre7` and `kotlin-stdlib-jre8`
>   instead.

Update other dependencies, if the automatic resolution doesn't work properly (**see point 5**).

---

### 2. Configure Gradle and Kotlin plugin updates

Revise your Gradle configuration. In order to [to build an Android project written in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#tarjeting-android):

- Set up the `kotlin-android` gradle plugin and apply it to your project.
- Add `kotlin-stdlib` dependencies.

> Those actions may also be performed automatically in IntelliJ IDEA /
>   AS by invoking the action:
>
> **Tools | Kotlin | Configure Kotlin in Project**

[image]

> Check for Kotlin plugin updates:
>
> **Tools | Kotlin | Configure Kotlin plugin updates**

[image]

---

### 3. kotlin-stdlib-jre7 renamed to kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 during the 1.2.x release

> Sirrah commented on 27 Dec 2017 [here:](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/5642#issuecomment-354124283)
>
> The Kotlin stdlib was renamed during the 1.2.x release. See [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/09/kotlin-1-2-beta-is-out/).
>
> The old name `kotlin-stdlib-jre7` was changed to `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`.
>
> This library is referenced in `realm-library` and `kotlin-extensions`.

---

### 4. Realm updated to Kotlin 1.2 in 4.3.2 version

> [Update Gradle Wrapper to 4.4.1 and Update to Kotlin
>   1.2](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/commit/35b57da8c656ceac849b6be87586ca8dbab69758)
>   ([#5642](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/5642))
>
> - Update Gradle Wrapper and Update to Kotlin 1.2
> - kotlin-stdlib-jre7 -> kotlin-stdlib-jdk7

[image]

---

### 5. Find conflictive dependencies via command, or build tab since AS 3.1

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration variantDebugCompileClasspath
```

[image]

Since Android Studio 3.1 Beta 1, you can use the new build tab to find the conflictive dependency:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this case, you removed the warning and fixed the issue updating Realm version to 4.3.2:

[image]

[image]

It's also possible to check it in Travis-ci builds considering the order dependencies are downloaded:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your extensive explanation. I didn't know Realm bundled Kotlin dependencies as well. The command for conflictive dependencies comes in handy for such cases.

Comment: @albodelu could you explain how to use the Build tab to find the conflicting dependency?

Comment: If I sun the gradlew to find which dependencies are creating conflicts, I get this error "Configuration with name 'variantDebugCompileClasspath' not found." Any help with this? I'm unable to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

what you can also do is to simply remove(or move) extra version folders. 
for example, remove one of the two folders below, then rebuild and that should get rid of the kotlin runtime warning.

~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.10

~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.10

Comment: Simply removing .gradle/caches/folder-name folder resolved my problem. Thanks @Jamie

Comment: Removing doesn't help me it simply puts it back when building.