# How to find dependencies of library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-architecture-components

I want to find dependencies of a library. For example, in my project, I `implement` android support library.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

When I execute `./gradlew :app:androidDependencies`,

- `android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0@aar`
- `android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0@jar`
- `android.arch.core:common:1.0.0@jar`

As you see, after 2017 Google IO, google import `Lifecycle` and other architecture components.

- How can `gradle` tool find dependencies of library(in this case, support 
  library)?
- For developer, is there any command to show dependencies of a library ?

Comment: Just using ./gradlew :app:androidDependencies, or reading the pom file related to the library

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti As you see,  ` ./gradlew :app:androidDependencies ` does not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check point 5 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47833237/1009132), and use **this command** or the new **Build** tab in Android Studio 3.1:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies

./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration 'productFlavors'DebugCompileClasspath
```

where `'productFlavors'` needs to be replaced by one of your product flavors like `production`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Configuration with name 'variantDebugCompileClasspath' not found.

Comment: It's a variant, a combination of flavor and buildType like `productionReleaseCompileClassPath`