# Why do I have different versions of Kotlin JARs in the classpath?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I decided to add a couple Kotlin files to an existing Java Android project in AS 3.0.

Once I added Kotlin files, I let the assistant add the appropriate lines to my `build.gradle` files, in particular:

`project build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    //...
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

`app build.gradle`

```
// top of file
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//....
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Unfortunately all builds now produce this warning:

```
Warning:Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
/Users/sddsfsd/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.21/88bfff5aa470143a83b0bc5ec00c0be8cabd7cad/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.21.jar (version 1.2)
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.51/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.51.jar (version 1.1)
/Users/sddsfsd/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.21/d64187eb2d9d1521be3421aa8c6774a8625cdde8/kotlin-stdlib-1.2.21.jar (version 1.2)
```

Why does Android Studio have its own older version of Kotlin in the classpath? How do I remove it?

Comment: Probably because IntelliJ has its own version of Kotlin so they control what's being used in their ecosystem. I'd start here: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-does-update-runtime-library-mean/4298

Comment: Do you have any other 3rd-party dependencies? Some of them might bring older versions of Kotlin libraries transitively.

Comment: @hotkey there are several, Firebase, Crashlytics, etc. Is there a way to get Android Studio to list the dependencies of those?

Comment: @hotkey And why would those dependencies put the JAR in `Android Studio.app/` instead of my own `.gradle` cache?

Comment: @ray You can make Gradle list the dependencies tree by running `./gradlew dependencies`. Fair point about the AS directory – seems like some of the Android built-in libraries brings older Kotlin stdlib with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why do I have different versions of Kotlin JARs in the classpath?

You have different versions because some of your dependencies depend on Kotlin 1.1 version.

> Why does Android Studio have its own older version of Kotlin in the
>   classpath? How do I remove it?

Updating your dependencies like I explained [here in a related question about renamed stdlib-jre7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47833237/1009132) and already explained [here for conflictive dependencies that have not been renamed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42569445/1009132).

[Kotlin reference - binary compatibility warnings](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compatibility.html#binary-compatibility-warnings):

> **Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version.**
>
> Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version.
>
> Consider removing them from the classpath.
>
> This means that you have a dependency on libraries of different
>   versions, for example the 1.1 standard library and the 1.0 reflection
>   library.
>
> To prevent subtle errors at runtime, we recommend you to use the same
>   version of all Kotlin libraries. In this case, consider adding an
>   explicit dependency.

In your case, the indirect dependency was renamed and you need to update the library that uses it:

**Find conflictive dependencies via command, or build tab since AS 3.1**

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration variantDebugCompileClasspath
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[In the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47833237/1009132), the warning was removed updating Realm version to 4.3.2.

**Note:** I checked my path and I also have outdated dependencies there but it's ok if you don't use it.