# Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I have a project which I use Dagger2 & kotlin, I imported `"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50”` in my build.gradle and I was getting this Error:

> w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version.
>   These files were found in the classpath:
>
> w:
>   /Users/macbook/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.51/8b5933578dc55f32cfc1a25f1db6371e4161fb8f/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.51.jar:
>   kotlin-stdlib-jre7 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk7
>   instead

So therefore I changed from `"kotlin-stdlib"` to `"kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"` using:
`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50”` and I am still getting this error.

I then made some research and found this URL: [warning: Kotlin runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569445/warning-kotlin-runtime-jar-files-in-the-classpath-should-have-the-same-version)

I found the usage of kotlin-reflect: `"implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.50"`

I added it to my build.gradle **BUT I still have the same errors**

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7: 1.3.50"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect: 1.3.50"
```

This is my BaseApplication class below, which I am calling the Dagger components :

```
class BaseApplication : Application() {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic lateinit var netComponent: NetComponent
        @JvmStatic lateinit var exampleComponent: ExampleComponent
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        netComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                .appModule(AppModule(this))
                .netModule(NetModule())
                .build()

        exampleComponent = DaggerExampleComponent.builder()
                .netComponent(netComponent)
                .retrofitModule(RetrofitModule())
                .exampleModule(ExampleModule(this))
                .build()

    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't actually post an error. Both stack texts are Warnings. `w:`