# Android :unimodules-react-native-adapter:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, react-native

I maintain a project in react-native 0.63.3 for a client.
Since yesterday morning, the build doesn't work anymore. No code has been changed.
Here is what the console says :

```
/Users/ME/DIR/CLIENT_NAME/PROJECT_NAME/node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/android/src/main/java/org/unimodules/adapters/react/services/CookieManagerModule.java:13: error: CookieManagerModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method invalidate() in NativeModule
```

Also, I had to perform another action before that (change my version of Kotlin, because it was suddenly not working, related to this post). [warning: Kotlin runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569445/warning-kotlin-runtime-jar-files-in-the-classpath-should-have-the-same-version)

I'm stuck for a day and a half... I don't know what to do anymore!

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
        firebaseVersion = "17.6.0"
        androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
        androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"
        androidXCore = "1.0.2"
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.10"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I tried to change the gradle distributions from 6.2 to 6.9, nothing change

Comment: This may be due to the recent react native publish (Every one having android build issue). Please check if this solution works https://stackoverflow.com/a/74334163/10657559

Comment: Wtf... men i just love you. THANKS A LOT !

Answer (score 1):

can u write this code response

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease --warning-mode=all
```

and i saw in npm js This package has been deprecated
[Check here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@unimodules/react-native-adapter)

Comment: Thanks mate, but the @Thanhal response fixed the problem for me. See you soon ! :)